# Using a variable with array of ElementIds to use in craft.entries.id

Tags: variable

I want to show entries according to an array.

This is my code:

```
            {% set navsubids = craft.amNav.getNavRaw("hoofdnavigatie", {startFromId:25})  %}
            {% set navsubidarray = [] %}

            {% for navsubid in navsubids %}
                    {% set navsubidarray = navsubidarray|merge([navsubid.elementId]) %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% set navsubidarray = navsubidarray|join(', ') %}

            {{ navsubidarray }}<br>

            {% for entry in craft.entries.id('{{ navsubidarray }}') %}
                {{ entry.title }}<br>
            {% endfor %}
```

The variable gives back that what I need `(18, 17, 19, 4, 20, 21, 22, 23)` but the for entry loop isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're getting the id's from but you will need to pass an array into `craft.entries.id` so try:

```
{% set navsubids = craft.amNav.getNavRaw("hoofdnavigatie", {startFromId:25})  %}

{% set navsubidarray = [] %}

{% for navsubid in navsubids %}
  {% set navsubidarray = navsubidarray|merge([navsubid.elementId]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.id( navsubidarray ) %}
  {{ entry.title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

When you used `{% set navsubidarray = navsubidarray|join(', ') %}` you were creating a string of the values in the array.

Answer (score 3):

Luke's answer above is correct, you might as well just use the array directly.

But technically you can use a joined string as well, it's just your syntax is wrong - you just call the variable directly:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.id(navsubidarray) %}
      {{ entry.title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

I just add this here in case it's ever useful to someone who for whatever reason wants to use a string of IDs in another scenario.